# How can you run different periodic tasks with timers with different intervals?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, task

I'm sure this question has been answered somewhere already but I'm trying to find a way here since a few hours and besides stepping over `Thread Timers` (which works fine for a periodic event, but not when the Timer has different variables and intervals to use) I didn't find anything. I'm really not sure of what to search for. A better thread title or description are greatly appreciated!

In a `Thread` I'm downloading a JSON which contains information about virtual items which values then are parsed and added into a ListView using `HTTPClient`. The JSON looks like this for each item (the item name is read from a TextBox and added to the request and ListView)

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "price":"31,98",
   "amount":"33"
}
```

The ListView contains 4 columns whereas in the Interval column the wanted refresh interval is entered.

```
Item Name    Price    Amount    Interval
```

My plan: I want to add Item Names and Intervals to the ListView with normal Text Boxes and a Button. Then I want to start Timers where each of these will read out the interval for a item and then refresh the prices of the corresponding item with the interval deposited in the List. There should be one Timer for each item which can do the HTTP Request independently of the other Timers.

The Thread works for one item at a time but it doesn't automatically refresh the values periodically;

```
private void getPrice()
        {
            try
            {
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                    JObject o = JObject.Parse(client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost/item.php?itemname=" + tb_MarketName.Text).Result);

                    string Price = (string)o["price"];
                    string Amount = (string)o["amount"];

                    lV_Items.Invoke((Action)delegate
                    {

                        ListViewItem items = new ListViewItem(tb_ItemName.Text));

                        items.SubItems.Add(Price);
                        items.SubItems.Add(Amount);
                        items.SubItems.Add(tb_Interval.Text);

                        lV_Items.Items.Add(items);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SendMail("Crash at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

What about having a single timer?  Set its interval to the lowest possible interval available in your list (let's say 1 minute for this example) with `AutoReset = true;`.  In the `Elapsed` event, scan through your list and determine which items are appropriate to update at the current time (based on their intervals and their last update time vs. current time), and add them to an `IEnumerable` collection.  So a line item that was last updated at 12:00PM, with an interval of 5 minutes, when the timer fires at 12:05PM.

Once you have your items in your collection, you can run a `Parallel.Foreach()` over the collection, inside calling your `getPrice()` code.  This will essentially multi-thread your updates without adding the clutter of all the `Timers`.  If you change `getPrice()` to an asynchronous method you can event prevent a long-running update (say 12:07PM) from preventing the next one (12:08PM).

Comment: Depending on what Timer class you use, the usage of multiple timers can limit your scalability. A single timer in task producer/consumer can be very useful as @chris has pointed out

Answer (score 1):

Try using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main").

This would be your entire code:

```
var subscription =
    lV_Items.ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(x =>
            Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x.Interval))
                .SelectMany(n =>
                    Observable
                        .Using(
                            () => new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(),
                            client => Observable.FromAsync(
                                () => client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost/item.php?itemname=" + x.MarketName)))
                        .Select(x => JObject.Parse(x))
                        .Select(o => new { lv_item = x, price = (string)o["price"], amount = (string)o["amount"] })))
        .ObserveOn(lV_Items)
        .Subscribe(result =>
        {
            result.lv_item.Amount = result.amount;
            result.lv_item.Price = result.price;
        });
```

To shut this all down you just call `subscription.Dispose();`.

You'd have to get the list view code working right as I've just done a quick kludge to show you what to do.